# How to get a label of a property from Wikidata?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I can use `rdfs:label` to get the text value of an object, for instance:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE {
  wd:Q19675 rdfs:label ?label . 
  FILTER (langMatches( lang(?label), "ES" ) )  
}
```

will give me the value `Museo del Louvre` since it is the label of the object `Q19675`.

But what if I want to get the label of a property? (Not-working) example:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  wdt:P131 rdfs:label ?label . 
}
```

What should I do to get the text value (label) of the property `P131`? The label of this property should be `located in the administrative territorial entity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution myself:

```
SELECT ?wdLabel WHERE {
  VALUES (?wdt) {(wdt:P131)}
   ?wd wikibase:directClaim ?wdt .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

We need `SERVICE wikibase:label...` only in order to specify the language of our property label.

Comment: [Here](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries#Adding_labels_for_properties) is also some additional info from the official Wikidata SPARQL/WDQS tutorial.